# CSS Background slideshow animation

Tags: css

I have **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/n27rk6qu/1/)** code

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
        <li><span>Image 01</span> </li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span> </li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span> </li>
        <li><span>Image 04</span> </li>
        <li><span>Image 05</span> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

In this demo as you can see, my content part also gets faded. I tried with lot of options but I didn't get solution

**Problem:**

My content div which is in red color must stay all the time, only background should animate. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
/* /background rotator */
 .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1)>span {
    background-image: url(http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/8932442_orig.jpg);
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2)>span {
    background-image: url(http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9899271_orig.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3)>span {
    background-image: url(http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/8932442_orig.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4)>span {
    background-image: url(http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/9899271_orig.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5)>span {
    background-image: url(http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/8932442_orig.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow, .cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content:'';
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family:'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: rgba(169, 3, 41, 0.8);
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */
 @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
/* Animation for the title */
 @-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(10);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
 .no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-size: 100px
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
        font-size: 50px
    }
}
/* /background rotator */
 .container {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:500px;
    background:red;
   z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="cb-slideshow ">
        <li><span>Image 01</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Image 04</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Image 05</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

You want like this ? M i right ?

Comment: check this line .cb-slideshow, .cb-slideshow:after write z-index:-1; in this class

Comment: after than write z-index:99; in .container class simple :)

Comment: k thanks .. didn't thought about z-index be the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The container is "hidden" because of the static position.
A quick fix: set it to absolute.

```
.container {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:500px;
    background:red;
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
}
```

(u might need some more position properties for your final styling (top, left...)

Updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/n27rk6qu/2/